latexmk in auctex
I would like to work with latexmk in continuous mode,
    (setq TeX-command-default "Latexmk")
    (push '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf -interaction=nonstopmode -pvc -synctex=1 %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
                :help "Run latexmk on file")
                 TeX-command-list)

PLUS reasonable error handling as in AUCTeX; that is, display the error message and jump to the error within the text buffer.
How can this be accomplished?

Not what you're asking, but personally, I never felt the need for latexmk using AUCTeX. I just run TeX-command-run-all, bound by default to C-c C-a. But perhaps you have other reasons to need latexmk.

I have encountered a couple of situations where AUCTeX did not compile correctly or not at all, but latexmk did. The problem occurs occasionally, often with inline literature, or after changes in external literature files.

If that's all, you should probably report it to AUCTeX devs.  ;-)  Besides, if it's occasional, you can always go with C-c C-c and choose what you want to run, then AUCTeX "catches up".

@AloisPichler - I suspect this is because AUCTeX doesn't know about the warning emitted by the package you're using.  Have a look at the value of TeX-LaTeX-sentinel; this is how AUCTeX parses the log file.

@AloisPichler - BTW, AUCTeX has support for LaTeXMk, if you're using a recent version, you can drop the (push ...) form and put (setq-default TeX-command-default "LaTeXMk") in your init-file in order to make a permanent change.

I think you're looking for the auctex-cont-latexmk library.  The description says:

This package provides a minor mode where latexmk continuously compiles
the document in the background and the errors/warnings are reported
via Flymake.

You can install the library from ELPA.
